# how do I detect that a popup menu has popped down without a selection?

Tags: popup, codenameone

If I use a combobox as a popup menu, how do I detect that it has been
dismissed without making a selection?

The underlying purpose is to remove it from the container's children.

Answer (score 0):

We generally just check if the value changed which I guess isn't what you are looking for.

FYI we try to avoid the combo box and use `Picker` which is implemented natively on the device and produces a more attractive result.